# Make column category and add it to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cut

I have the data like this and I want to make **age categories** based on **P_ID column** and store it in a new column **AgeCatg**. I followed [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69175023/how-to-make-column-value-categories-and-add-to-a-new-column) but have some issues.

| Age | P_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 51 | 1 |
| 51 | 1 |
| 51 | 1 |
| 28 | 2 |
| 28 | 2 |
| 28 | 2 |
| 28 | 2 |
| 35 | 3 |
| 35 | 3 |
| 35 | 3 |
| 35 | 3 |
| 89 | 4 |
| 89 | 4 |
| 89 | 4 |
| 89 | 4 |
| 14 | 5 |
| 14 | 5 |
| 38 | 6 |
| 38 | 6 |
| 38 | 6 |

The **required output** is as follows:

| Age | P_ID | AgeCatg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 51 | 1 | 50-60 |
| 51 | 1 | 50-60 |
| 28 | 2 | 20-30 |
| 28 | 2 | 20-30 |
| 28 | 2 | 20-30 |
| 28 | 2 | 20-30 |
| 35 | 3 | 30-40 |
| 35 | 3 | 30-40 |
| 35 | 3 | 30-40 |
| 35 | 3 | 30-40 |
| 89 | 4 | 80-90 |
| 89 | 4 | 80-90 |
| 89 | 4 | 80-90 |
| 89 | 4 | 80-90 |
| 14 | 5 | 10-20 |
| 14 | 5 | 10-20 |
| 38 | 6 | 30-40 |
| 38 | 6 | 30-40 |
| 38 | 6 | 30-40 |

I tried the following code and then plotted the graph but there is an issue.

```
print(f'The minimum age is {v.Age.min()} and maximum age is {v.Age.max()}.')
# Output
The minimum age is 14 and maximum age is 89.
v['AgeCatg'] = pd.cut(v['Age'], np.arange(9, 90, 10), labels=[f'{x}-{x + 10}' for x in np.arange(10, 89, 10)])
v['AgeCatg'].value_counts().sort_index()

# Output
10-20    2
20-30    4
30-40    7
40-50    0
50-60    3
60-70    0
70-80    0
80-90    4

# Graph
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6));
ax = sns.countplot(data=v, x='AgeCatg', palette="tab10")
ax.set_title("Patient count Age category wise", y = 1)
ax.set_ylabel('Total Count')
ax.set_xlabel('Age Categories')
for rect in ax.patches:
    y_value = rect.get_height()
    x_value = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2
    space = 1
    label = "{:.0f}".format(y_value)
    ax.annotate(label, (x_value, y_value), xytext=(0, space), textcoords="offset points", ha='center', va='bottom')
```

[image]

Here, the code is plotting total number of rows that fall in the category, but I want to plot patients counts, not the patient rows. Like, **P_ID 3 and 6** lies in **AgeCatg 30-40**, so the **graph should plot 2** above the bar, not the **total number of rows that are 7**. I think the problem is where I used `pd.cut()`. I tried the following but it gave wrong result.

```
x['AgeCatg'] = pd.cut(x.groupby('P_ID')['Age'].first(), np.arange(9, 90, 10), labels=[f'{x}-{x + 10}' for x in np.arange(10, 89, 10)])
```

Please help. Thanks.

#### Update

After **P. Pinho** Answer, I applied the code on my real data. It worked perfectly. However There is a little issue on x-axis labels of graph. Please have a look and let me know how it can be like 10-20, 20-30, 30-40 ... instead of 10-20, 100-110, 20-30, ... Thanks

[image]

Comment: The issue on the `x axis` is happening because the values are `strings` and they are sorted as such, hence all numbers 1 first. All you have to do is set another sorting method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age' :[51,51,51,28,28,28,28,35,35,35,35,89,89,89,89,14,14,38,38,38],
                   'P_ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6]})
```

`EDIT 1`: In order to create the `AgeCatg` column I created a list populated by a `fstring`. The `//` operator returns the floor division. For instance: **51//10 = 5**, if we mutiply by **10**, we get the decimal we are looking for. If we add **10**, we have the proper time window.

```py
df['AgeCatg'] = [f'{i//10*10}-{i//10*10+10}' for i in df['Age']]
```

Output:

```
df

   Age  P_ID  AgeCatg
 0  51     1    50-60
 1  51     1    50-60
 2  51     1    50-60
 3  28     2    20-30
 4  28     2    20-30
 5  28     2    20-30
 6  28     2    20-30
 7  35     3    30-40
 8  35     3    30-40
 9  35     3    30-40
10  35     3    30-40
11  89     4    80-90
12  89     4    80-90
13  89     4    80-90
14  89     4    80-90
15  14     5    10-20
16  14     5    10-20
17  38     6    30-40
18  38     6    30-40
19  38     6    30-40
```

Graph:

```py
df.groupby('AgeCatg').agg({'P_ID': 'nunique'}).plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10,6), title='Patient count Age category wise');
```

Output:

[image: bar graph]

Comment: Can you please elaborate what does this f-string do?

Comment: Also, when I applied the code on my real data, I have a little issue in my graph. The index is not correctly placed. Please check my question. I updated it

Comment: @Optimus, I edited my answer in order to better explain the `fstring` solution. About the `index` problem, I commented on your updated post.